# What is the cheapest ways to get the combinations of all rotated and reflected matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigen

I'm using eigen and I wonder what the cheapest ways will be to get the combinations of all rotated and reflected matrices. Let's I have a matrix like:

```
1 2
4 3
```

And I want all rotated matrices:

```
1 2
4 3
---------
4 1
3 2
---------
3 4
2 1
---------
2 3
1 4
```

And reflected:

```
1 4
2 3
---------
4 3
1 2
---------
3 2
4 1
---------
2 1
3 4
---------
```

Comment: How is `[4 1; 3 2]` a rotation of `[1 2; 3 4]` (same for all other rotations/reflections)?

Comment: @chtz think about you are playing a board game and you are sitting on all 4 sides of the board to observe the board.

Comment: I agree with @chtz maybe you wrote the initial matrix wrong? If it was `[1 2; 4 3]` then yeah `[4 1; 2 3]` would be a rotation in the board game sense

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad. I updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can flip horizontally using `A.rowwise().reverse()`, vertically using `A.colwise().reverse()` and on the main diagonal using `A.transpose()`. `A.reverse()` rotates by 180 degrees, everything else can be achieved by a combination of the above:

```
Eigen::Matrix2i A; A << 1, 2, 4, 3;

std::cout << "Original:\n" << A << '\n';
std::cout << "Rot 90:\n" << A.transpose().colwise().reverse() << '\n';
std::cout << "Rot 180:\n" << A.reverse() << '\n';
std::cout << "Rot 270:\n" << A.transpose().rowwise().reverse() << '\n';


std::cout << "Flip horizontal:\n" << A.rowwise().reverse() << '\n';
std::cout << "Flip vertical:\n" << A.colwise().reverse() << '\n';
std::cout << "Flip main diag:\n" << A.transpose() << '\n';
std::cout << "Flip side diag:\n" << A.transpose().reverse() << '\n';
```

When compiled with optimizations, all these functions are zero cost, i.e., they just create a view on the underlying matrix.